# Как очистить значение одного из полей модели Django для всех сущностей?

Tags: sql, django

Здравствуйте! У меня в проете Django в модели пользователя есть поле img (фотография). Мне нужно удалить для всех пользователей фотографии. Пробую в API написать соответствующий запрос, были попытки `User.img.all().delete`, `p=User.objects.all().get`, затем `p.img.all().delete`, `for user in p: user.img.delete()`, но правильно написать не получается, выдаются разные ошибки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) для QuerySet:

```
User.objects.all().update(img='')
```

или `img=None` если у вас поле по умолчанию null

Comment: Спасибо, получилось! Правда сначала выдавалась ошибка `mysql server has gone away`. Если я правильно поняла, из-за установленного по умолчанию объема запроса. По крайней мере после того, как я его изменила, ошибка болше не выдавалась.